# Javascript: how to copy a object and keep its prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, copy, prototype-chain

I have an object:

```
var obj = {
     name: "Mike"
}

// and its prototype property:
obj.__proto__:
   say: function () {...}
   walk: function () {...}
```

I want copy it and keep the `__proto__`

first I thought jQuery `$.extend` method:

`$.extend({}, obj)`

but what is return would merge the `__proto__` like:

```
{
    name: "Lee",
    say: function () {},
    walk: function () {}
}
```

so how can I copy the object with keep the prototype chain?

Answer (score 1):

Firet of all, what kind of copy do you want? Deep copy or shallow copy? Assume that you want shallow copy; just copy `src`'s own properties(unless `dest` already has same property) and `__proto__` to `dest`.

```
function copy(dest, src) {
    var p;
    for (p in src) {
        if (src.hasOwnProperty(p) && !dest.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            dest[p] = src[p];
        }
    }
    dest.__proto__ = src.__proto__;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U6uY4

If you want deep copy, replace `for .. in` loop to deep copy algorithm that fits with your use case.

---

Note that this is uncommon requirement. I suggest you think again what do you really want to do.

Comment: You had to mention it in question. Anyway, do you really want to deep copy? Deep copy in JavaScript is very difficult than you think. Does your property can be `RegExp` or `Date`? Do you have any use case for that situation? Consider this, then google *javascript deep copy* and choose most appropriate method, then replace `for .. in` loop to that.

Comment: Thank you. I've used this line to clone the object and change a single property:
```
    let clone = Object.setPrototypeOf({ ...this, scanned }, this.__proto__);
```
It seems to work.